# Split xml complex node elements into multiple nodes using xslt

Tags: xml, split, xmlnode

Is there a way to split a parent node into multiple nodes using xslt?

I want to transform the source xml into destination.

Source xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <item>
                <id>Some id</id>
                <node1>
                    <node2 size="10.5" code="abcd"></node2>
                    <node2 size="10" code="cdef"></node2>        
                </node1>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

Destination xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <item>
                <id>Some id_10.5</id>
                <size>10.5</size>
                <code>abcd</code>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Some id_10</id>
                <size>10</size>
                <code>cdef</code>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

If you notice the value of node id in destination xml, it has an underscore and size appended to it.

Comment: Can somebody please help me in completing the solution given by Michael below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very straightforward, it's not clear why you are finding it difficult.

```
<xsl:template match="node2">
            <item>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="../../id"/>_<xsl:value-of select="@size"/></id>
                <size><xsl:value-of select="@size"/></size>
                <code><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></code>
            </item> 
</xsl:template>
```

plus some trivial template rules for other elements.

Comment: Thanks @Michael
But there some problem with it.
I put the following line before the template

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

and this line after the template

</xsl:stylesheet>
But the destination xml had the first value of node id appearing before the first item node. Sorry but i am noob.

Comment: Well, I think StackOverflow is a good place for getting a specific solution to a specific problem, but it's not good for saying "please teach me basic XSLT". There are books for that - I've written one of them - and I recommend you read it.